# Find the pointwise limit and determine if convergence is uniform

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)=nx^n(1-x^n)$ and determine if the convergence is uniform.

**Solution**

For $x=1$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(nx^n(1-x^n))\to 0$$

For $0\le x<1$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(nx^n(1-x^n))\to0$$

as $x^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thus the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is $f(x)=0$.

Determine if the convergence is uniform:

We use,
$$\sup\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert<\epsilon$$

$$\sup\vert nx^n(1-x^n)-0\vert$$

$$\sup\vert nx^n(1-x^n)\vert$$
$$\sup \vert nx^n-nx^{2n}\vert$$

We want too find the largest possible value of this function, we take the derivative set to $0$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}(nx^n-nx^{2n})=0$$
$$n^2x^{n-1}-2n^2x^{2n-1}=0$$
$$x^{n-1}-2x^{2n-1}=0$$
$$x^{n-1}(1-2x^{n})=0$$
We can then find the trivial solution $x^{n-1}=0$ and the solution,
$$x=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}}$$

**Is this a correct solution? Or have I made an error?**

As $n\to\infty$, $\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}\to1$, which is obviously not the largest value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pointwise limit is O.K.

Furthermore: $f_n(\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{n}{4}$ for all $n$. This shows that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you, I used $x^n=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}}$ not $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is always interesting to plot graphical representations concretizing algebraic/analytic proofs. Here it is for the 8 first curves with coordinates of maximum (red stars)

$$(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}, \ \frac{n}{4}).$$

[image]